# Is there a way for me to encrypt and decrypt a message given a key in a single method in java?

Tags: java, encryption, caesar-cipher

I am new to programming and have only done Python in the past. Currently, I am working on a university assignment that requires me to implement a Caesar Cipher. Firstly, I was given an interface called "Cipher" and am tasked to write a class called "RotationCipher" that implements this interface.

The interface:

```
public interface Cipher {

/**
 * Encodes the given plain text into a secret cipher text
 * 
 * @param plainText the plain text to encode
 * @return the cipher text
 */
abstract public String encrypt(String plainText);

/**
 * Determines the plain text string for a given cipher text.
 * 
 * @param cipherText the cipher text to decode
 * @return the plain text original
 */

abstract public String decrypt(String cipherText);
}
```

Class RotationCipher that implements the interface:

```
abstract class RotationCipher implements Cipher {

protected int shift;

public RotationCipher(int key) {
    shift = key;
}

protected String text;

protected abstract String rotate(int shift, String text);

public String encrypt(String plainText) {
    String cipherText = rotate(shift, plainText);
    return cipherText;
}

public String decrypt(String cipherText) {
    shift = shift - 26;
    String plainText = rotate(shift, cipherText);
    return plainText;
}
}
```

The subclass CaesarCipher that extends from class RotationCipher (meant to both encrypt and decrypt a message given a key):

```
public class CaesarCipher extends RotationCipher{

public CaesarCipher(int key){
    super (key);
    }

public String rotate(int shift, String text) {
    String cipherTxt = "";
    String plainTxt = "";

    if(shift>26) {
        shift = shift%26;
    }else if(shift < 0) {
        shift = (shift%26) + 26;
    }

    int length = text.length();
    for(int i = 0; i < length; i++) {

        char ch = text.charAt(i);

        if(Character.isLetter(ch)) {
            if(Character.isLowerCase(ch)) {
                char c = (char)(ch + shift);
                if(c > 'z') {
                    cipherTxt = cipherTxt + (char)(ch - (26 - shift));
                }else {
                    cipherTxt = cipherTxt + c;
                }

            }else if(Character.isUpperCase(ch)) {
                char c = (char)(ch + shift);
                if(c > 'Z') {
                    cipherTxt = cipherTxt + (char)(ch - (26 - shift));
                }else if(ch == 'X') {
                    cipherTxt = cipherTxt + (char)(ch -(26 - shift));
                }
                else {
                    cipherTxt = cipherTxt + c;
                }
            }
        }else if(Character.isLetter(ch) == false) {
            cipherTxt = cipherTxt + ch;
        }

    }
    return cipherTxt;
}
}
```

It is also mentioned to me by my lecturer that encoding and decoding are essentially the same operation but with inverted keys. I believe the "rotate" method is supposed to both encrypt and decrypt a given text by a given key. Instead, I have only managed to encrypt a give text with a given key but I have no idea at all on how to do the opposite in this same method. Is there a way for me to do this and what changes should be made?

Comment: Your lecturer seems to have misled you; decoding simply requires the `shift` be negated. For example, if `shift` was *ten* (`10`) on encoding then `shift` must be *negative ten* (`-10`) on decoding.

Comment: @ElliotFrisch my lecturer has also given a java application to test the program and apparently a negative key encryption is also included in the test. Is there a way to make the program differentiate between a negative key that is meant to decrypt the message and a negative key that is meant to encrypt the message?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of. That would be an interesting property of any value.

Comment: The rotate method just rotates for a given amount that is determined by the current key value. When you call the encrypt/decrypt the value key adjusted before rotation is called. I think your lecturer's intention is a given key is for encryption and it's inverse mod 26 is the decryption.